# Single electron transfer periodic DFT in VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, electronic-transport, free-energy

I have the following question: I am currently studying the electrocatalytic $\ce{CO2}$ reduction reaction [(CO2RR)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_reduction_of_carbon_dioxide#Electrocatalysis) on $\ce{Cu}$ materials using periodic DFT calculations and I am using the Computational Hydrogen Electrode [(CHE)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp047349j) model to describe the proton electron transfer reactions, as follows:

$$\ce{CO2^* +e- + H+ → COOH^*}$$
$$\Delta G= G(\ce{COOH^*})-G(*)-G(CO2)-G(e^- + \ce{H+})=G(\ce{COOH^*})-G(*)-G(\ce{CO2})-\frac{1}{2}G(\ce{H2}\text{(gas)}$$

Nonetheless, I would like to ask how to describe reactions where I have only an electron transfer for example:

$$
\ce{COOH^* +e- → COOH- (aq)}+ *.
$$

**How do I add calculate the Gibbs free energy of the electron added, as well as how I add the extra electron to the $\ce{COOH-}$ (aq)?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By DG do you mean $\Delta G$? But +1 and welcome to the site anyway! Please do let us know if you get an answer in one of the other places you asked it, such as here: https://m.facebook.com/groups/545831582699025/permalink/804887936793387/

Comment: yes I mean Delta G

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? Do you have any update you could give us about what you've learned about this problem over the last 9+ months?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.